# Qt5. The signal of QMediaPlayer bufferStatusChanged(int) not works

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

My environment is `Qt5 32bit` `Windows 7 64bit` `MSVC 2010 32bit`

My code is a simple music player

this is main code

```
slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 100);
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D://test.mp3"));
player->setVolume(50);
...
connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

When I run this player, it could play music, but the value of the `slider` never changed.

then I add this:

```
connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(helloWorld(int)));
...
void player::helloWorld(int)
{
    qDebug() << "hello, world";
}
```

I run it again, and found the string `hello, world` never be printed.

not printed anything.

Why the value of the `slider` not be changed?

-------------------------full code--------------------------

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    mainWidget = new QWidget();
    HLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    VLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

    playButton = new QPushButton("Okay");
    exitButton = new QPushButton("Exit");
    slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    player = new QMediaPlayer();

    connect(playButton, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(playOrPause(bool)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), this, SLOT(test(int)));
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D://test.mp3"));
    player->play();
    player->setVolume(50);
    slider->setRange(0, 100);


    //UI
    exitButton->setAutoDefault(true);
    playButton->setAutoDefault(true);
    playButton->setCheckable(true);

    HLayout->addStretch();
    HLayout->addWidget(playButton);
    HLayout->addWidget(exitButton);

    VLayout->addWidget(slider);
    VLayout->addStretch();
    VLayout->addLayout(HLayout);

    mainWidget->setLayout(VLayout);

    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/icon.png"));
    setWindowTitle("YUCOAT");

    //connect(playButton, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(playOrPause(bool)));
    //connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::playOrPause(bool s)
{
    if (s)
        player->play();
    else
        player->pause();

}

void MainWindow::test(int s)
{
    qDebug() << "hello, world!";
    qDebug() << s;
    qDebug() << player->mediaStatus();
}
```

Comment: Is there any debug output in the console? Qt normally reports errors there when it can't connect a signal to a slot.

Comment: no, not output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qmediaplayer.html#bufferStatus-prop) :

> When the player object is buffering; this property holds the
>   percentage of the temporary buffer that is filled. The buffer will
>   need to reach 100% filled before playback can resume, at which time
>   the MediaStatus will be BufferedMedia.

You are making the connection **after** loading the media so probably the buffer is already in a `QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia` state so the signal will not get emited. You could check it by printing the [media status](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatus-prop) before the connection:

```
qDebug() << player->mediaStatus();
```